# Как вытащить данные с другого сайта

Tags: curl, php

Здравствуйте! 
Возникла следующая проблема: Google отказался от FeedBurner API - использовалось для вывода числа подписчиков на блог на сайте.
Пока еще можно получить эти данные через http://feeds.feedburner.com/~fc/**FeedBurner-ID**
но такой вариант совсем не устраивает
С другой стороны, blograte.ru все же выводит в текстовом виде количество подписчиков, например,
[blograte.ru](http://blograte.ru/%2563%2561%2574%2565%2567%256f%2572%2579/id/1/page/2/)

Как можно вытащить эти данные либо с blograte.ru либо с feedburner ?

Comment: вы же сами ответили на свой вопрос, правильно проставив метки. curl & php.. @abibock_un подсказал простой вариант, с curl оно правильнее, но и то и то можно использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать функцию file_get_contents:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents($url);
```

и при помощи регулярного выражения вытащите нужные данные из исходного кода страницы вебсайта $url

Более подробно [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)